# How to test child class methods only without instantiating base class in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I am a newbie of Python, I need to test the child class methods without initializing a base class instance  because in the base class , there are lots of dependencies on network and some other components, my child class methods are 
standalone.

I tried to create a new child class by removing the base class methods from the child class,but it can't work. Here are the codes.

```
def remove_base(child_cls, base_cls):
    allmembers = inspect.getmembers(child_cls, predicate=inspect.ismethod)
    allmembers_dict = dict(allmembers)
    hbasemembers = inspect.getmembers(base_cls, predicate=inspect.ismethod)
    hbase_dict = dict(hbasemembers)
    child_class_member = set(allmembers_dict.keys()) - set(hbase_dict.keys())
    new_dict = {}
    for key in allmembers_dict.keys():
        for child_member in child_class_member:
            if key == child_member:
                new_dict[key] = allmembers_dict[key]
    return new_dict

class A:
    def add(self, i):
        print i + 1

class B(A):
    def sub(self, i):
        print i - 1

newB = type("newB", (object, ), remove_base(B, A))
b = newB()
b.sub(5)
```

The error message is :

> TypeError: unbound method sub() must be called with B instance as
>   first argument (got int instance instead)

I think the way of removing base class methods may be wrong.
How to handle this problem?

Comment: Override the parent methods without calling `super` so only the child implementation wouild be called

Comment: The thing that is wrong is your inheritance structure. If you child methods are completely independent of the parent, then you shouldn't be inheriting at all.

Comment: Could you give a less abstract example? In your current example, the obvious answer is to make both of those methods `@staticmethod`, as they don't use `self` at all, then test e.g. `B.sub` without instantiating anything. Without context, this seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248731).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `__dict__` from `B` directly:

```
class A(object):
    def add(self, i):
        print(i + 1)

class B(A):
    def sub(self, i):
        print(i - 1)

newB = type("newB", (object, ), dict(B.__dict__))
b = newB()
b.sub(5)
```